# Linux Screen window title keeps changing

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Screen window titles keep getting changed to hostname: everytime I go to a new directory. Need to preserve the manual name changes of the windows.

Here is all of the /etc/screenrc config. Please note that it's an IT managed machine and I can't change this file.

```
deflogin on
vbell on
vbell_msg "   Wuff  ----  Wuff!!  "
termcap  facit|vt100|xterm|xterm-* LP:G0
terminfo facit|vt100|xterm|xterm-* LP:G0
termcap  vt100 dl=5\E[M
terminfo vt100 dl=5\E[M
termcap  facit al=\E[L\E[K:AL@:dl@:DL@:cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:ic@
terminfo facit al=\E[L\E[K:AL@:dl@:DL@:cs=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr:ic@
termcap  sun 'up=^K:AL=\E[%dL:DL=\E[%dM:UP=\E[%dA:DO=\E[%dB:LE=\E[%dD:RI=\E[%dC:IC=\E[%d@:WS=1000\E[8;%d;%dt'
terminfo sun 'up=^K:AL=\E[%p1%dL:DL=\E[%p1%dM:UP=\E[%p1%dA:DO=\E[%p1%dB:LE=\E[%p1%dD:RI=\E[%p1%dC:IC=\E[%p1%d@:WS=\E[8;%p1%d;%p2%dt$<1000>'
termcap  hp700 'Z0=\E[?3h:Z1=\E[?3l:hs:ts=\E[62"p\E[0$~\E[2$~\E[1$}:fs=\E[0}\E[61"p:ds=\E[62"p\E[1$~\E[61"p:ic@'
terminfo hp700 'Z0=\E[?3h:Z1=\E[?3l:hs:ts=\E[62"p\E[0$~\E[2$~\E[1$}:fs=\E[0}\E[61"p:ds=\E[62"p\E[1$~\E[61"p:ic@'
termcap wy75-42 nx:xo:Z0=\E[?3h\E[31h:Z1=\E[?3l\E[31h
terminfo wy75-42 nx:xo:Z0=\E[?3h\E[31h:Z1=\E[?3l\E[31h
bind ^k
bind ^\
bind \\ quit
bind K kill
bind I login on
bind O login off 
bind } history
startup_message off 
pow_detach_msg "Screen session of $LOGNAME $:cr:$:nl:ended."
defscrollback 1000
termcapinfo xterm* OL=100
termcapinfo xterm|xterm-* 'VR=\E[?5h:VN=\E[?5l'
termcapinfo xterm|xterm-* 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007'
termcapinfo   xterm|xterm-* 'XC=K%,%\E(B,[\304,\\\\\326,]\334,{\344,|\366,}\374,~\337'
termcapinfo xterm* be
termcapinfo wy75-42 xo:hs@
termcapinfo wy* CS=\E[?1h:CE=\E[?1l:vi=\E[?25l:ve=\E[?25h:VR=\E[?5h:VN=\E[?5l:cb=\E[1K:CD=\E[1J
termcapinfo  hp700 'Z0=\E[?3h:Z1=\E[?3l:hs:ts=\E[62"p\E[0$~\E[2$~\E[1$}:fs=\E[0}\E[61"p:ds=\E[62"p\E[1$~\E[61"p:ic@'

termcap  vt100* ms:AL=\E[%dL:DL=\E[%dM:UP=\E[%dA:DO=\E[%dB:LE=\E[%dD:RI=\E[%dC
terminfo vt100* ms:AL=\E[%p1%dL:DL=\E[%p1%dM:UP=\E[%p1%dA:DO=\E[%p1%dB:LE=\E[%p1%dD:RI=\E[%p1%dC
termcapinfo linux C8
hardstatus string "[screen %n%?: %t%?] %h"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was related to bash PROMPT_COMMAND. The screen window title gets changed according to PROMPT_COMMAND. So just unset PROMPT_COMMAND for workaround.